# How to test for database connection issues?

Tags: c#

In our application, we notice recently that there are some codes that will create database connections call unnecessary e.g every data row in the data set is making a database connection call to check certain data.

How can we monitor these kind of issue either via code scanning or database queries monitoring? Any advises?

Comment: _there are some codes that will create database connections_ what does that mean? An ORM? An external library? **Who** is making external calls?

Comment: This isn't very clear, but I am assuming you mean profiling? You mentioned "unnecessary calls" so I assume you mean you want to performance tune your database calls. The Mini Profiler created by some of the SO guys works well for us: http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/

Comment: This library might be helpful: http://miniprofiler.com/

Comment: For clarification. He is saying people wrongfully set up database connections and a query is being executed on a per row basis, rather than a batch. He is asking how there problems can be identified in the future, can one monitor db queries to determine if they are being done inneficiently, e.g one at a time

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of **"SQL Profiler"** if you are using MS SQL. Anyway code walk through must give you idea about it.

Put Some debug prints in the database connection method so that you can track of connections made and its sources.